# Groupwise maximum record lookup for contracts and latest status

Tags: mysql, groupwise-maximum

I'm looking for help as I can't seem to get a handle on a SQL query.

I have two tables:

- Contracts - where the list of contracts is kept along with the associated partners

```sql
CREATE TABLE `contracts` (
  `id` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
  `partner` varchar(12) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`)
)
```

- locks - list of contract statuses

```sql
CREATE TABLE `locks` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `type` enum('unlock','templock','lock','permalock') DEFAULT NULL,
  `contractID` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
  `partnerID` varchar(12) NOT NULL,
  `stamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp() ON UPDATE current_timestamp(),
  `user` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`)
)
```

I am trying to get a list of the latest contract statuses for a given partner:

```sql
SELECT c.id, c.partner ,l.`type`, l.stamp, l.id 
FROM contracts c 
LEFT JOIN locks l
ON c.id = l.contractID 
WHERE partner="2000000301"
GROUP BY c.id ASC
```

I was able to get the result, but it doesn't indicate the last status correctly - it "takes" the first one occurring :(, and I need the last one.

I tried the sequential approach, i.e. I first made a query that retrieves the last state for the contract:

```sql
SELECT max(l.id), l.partnerID ,l.contractID ,l.stamp ,l.`type`  
FROM locks l
WHERE l.partnerID = "2000000301" and l.contractID ="35274";
```

It works fine, but if I tried to implement this to the main query, using 'LEFT JOIN(...)'

```sql
SELECT *
FROM contracts
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT max(ll.id), ll.contractID, ll.partnerID, ll.stamp, ll.`type`
  FROM locks ll
  WHERE ll.partnerID = contracts.partner <-- error :(
) l
ON contracts.id = l.contractID 
WHERE partner="2000000301"
ORDER BY contracts.id ASC
```

Here there is a problem with the availability of the 'contractID' field from the 'contracts' table and I get an error :(

`SQL Error [1054] [42S22]: (conn=180) Unknown column 'contracts.partner' in 'where clause'`

I had already lost the concept of approach.

Comment: You cannot outer join using a *correlation*, and your sub-query is malformed, you are aggregating without a *group by*

Comment: I understand that the subquery should return records with only the most recent statuses for a given partner and in this form, it should go to the main question.
I have constructed such query: `SELECT l.partnerID ,l.contractID ,l.stamp ,l.type FROM locks l WHERE l.partnerID = "2000000301" GROUP BY l.contractID;` but it does not return the last status for the contract.

Comment: OK. I was able to put together a query that produces the result: each contractor and its last status change. `SELECT l.contractID, l.partnerID, l.stamp, l.type. FROM locks l INNER JOIN (SELECT contractID, max(id) as max_id FROM locks GROUP BY contractID) m ON l.contractID=m.contractID and l.id=m.max_id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called a [groupwise-maximum](/questions/tagged/groupwise-maximum) problem.

It looks like your `locks` table gets updated sometimes, and those updates change the `stamp` timestamp column.  So your problem is to report out the latest -- most recent in time -- `locks` record for each `contractID`.  Start with a subquery to determine the latest `stamp` for each contract.

```sql
                 SELECT MAX(stamp) stamp, contractID
                   FROM locks
                  GROUP BY contractID
```

Then use that subquery in your main query to choose the appropriate row of `locks`.

```sql
SELECT c.id ,c.partner ,l.stamp ,l.`type`
  FROM contracts c
  LEFT JOIN (
                 SELECT MAX(stamp) stamp, contractID
                   FROM locks
                  GROUP BY contractID
       ) latest ON c.contractID=latest.contractID  
  LEFT JOIN locks l   ON c.contractID = l.contractID
                     AND latest.stamp = l.stamp
 WHERE c.partner="2000000301"
 ORDER BY c.id ASC
```

Notice that the latest `locks` record is not necessarily the one with the largest `id` value.

This index will help the query's performance when your locks table is large, by enabling the subquery to do a [loose index scan](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-optimization.html#loose-index-scan).

```
ALTER TABLE locks ADD INDEX contractid_stamp (contractID, stamp);
```

And, you don't need both a PRIMARY KEY and a UNIQUE KEY on the same column. The PRIMARY KEY serves the purpose of guaranteeing uniqueness. Putting both keys on the table slows down INSERTs for no good reason.

Comment: Thank you, you have nicely elaborated this for me. You are correct in looking at the `stamp`, however, it may happen (and I assume such a situation) that the `stamp` for several records may be the same and then the problem arises which is last. Hence my approach via `id`, which always increases, when adding records to `locks`. I don't provide for changes in the `locks` records so, the highest `id` will always be the last one. I was thinking myself that surely this subquery must consist of one more query, and here you go. One more LEFT JOIN :) It's not a problem. It's a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think it worked :)

```sql
SELECT c.id ,c.partner ,l.stamp ,l.`type`
FROM contracts c
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT l.contractID, l.partnerID, l.stamp, l.`type`
    FROM locks l INNER JOIN (
      SELECT contractID, max(id) as max_id
      FROM locks
      group by contractID
    ) m
    ON l.contractID=m.contractID and l.id=m.max_id  
) l
ON c.id = l.contractID 
WHERE c.partner="2000000301"
ORDER BY c.id ASC
```